# Tizen Studio step SDB shell handle failed

Tags: tizen, tizen-studio, tizen-tv

I am trying my hand at Tizen TV App Development and every time i try to launch, I get an error saying: "Step SDB shell handle failed" And when I click details

`step SDB shell handle failed Failed to step SDB shell handle ls /usr/bin/xwalk-launcher > /tmp/null.deployer 2>&1; echo $?  command operation sdb command rejected exception`

if someone here could help out please

Answer (score 0):

We need to know your Dev. environments for deep analysis.

- What is the SDK version you used?
- Have you installed samsung tv extension?
- What is the connected target? (Emulator or Real TV target)
- Have you used Samsung Certificates for signing App?